# How do I show that $R=\Bbb{Z}_{(2)}\left[\sqrt{-3}\right]$ is a noetherian ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian

> Let me take an extension ring of the localization $\Bbb{Z}_{(2)}$ of $\Bbb{Z}$ which is not a DVR:
> $$R=\Bbb{Z}_{(2)}\left[\sqrt{-3}\right]$$

I want to show that $R$ is a noetherian ring.

My idea was the following. We know that $R=\Bbb{Z}_{(2)}\left[\sqrt{-3}\right]=(\Bbb{Z}\setminus (2))^{-1}\Bbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{-3}\right]$. But now I know that $\Bbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{-3}\right]\cong \Bbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+3)$. Since $\Bbb{Z}[X]$ is noetherian and $(X^2+3)$ is an ideal we know by a corollary of Hilbert's basis theorem that $\Bbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{-3}\right]$ is noetherian. But then localization doesn't affect noetherianity so it is also still noetherian.

Does this work?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't remember off the top of my head how much work it takes to show you can interchange localization with adjoinment, but it's not necessary; you can just use the fact that $\mathbb Z_{(2)}$ is noetherian.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein ah and then adjoinment is also noetherian?

Comment: Exactly, Hilbert basis theorem like you already said.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein but I mean this said if $R$ is a noetherian ring then $R[X]$ is noetherian so the polynomial ring over $R$ and not the adjoinment?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein or am I wrong?

Comment: We're simply saying that $\mathbb Z$ noetherian $\implies \mathbb Z_{(2)}$ noetherian, $\implies \mathbb Z_{(2)}[X]$ noetherian $\implies  \mathbb Z_{(2)}[X]/(X^2+3)$ noetherian.

Comment: @rschwieb ah so you use the isomorphism I gave above?

Comment: @Haveaniceday I thought that went without saying, yes.

Comment: @rschwieb sorry I was a bit confused. Was a long day. Thank you now it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a point of clarification from the comments: neither of the isomorphisms $\Bbb{Z}_{(2)}\left[\sqrt{-3}\right]=(\Bbb{Z}\setminus (2))^{-1}\Bbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{-3}\right]$ nor $\Bbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{-3}\right]\cong \Bbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+3)$, nor, for that matter, the upstairs analogue $\Bbb{Z}_{(2)}\left[\sqrt{-3}\right]\cong \Bbb{Z}_{(2)}[X]/(X^2+3)$, are necessary here.

Step 1. $\mathbb Z_{(2)}$ is Noetherian. You understand this part.

Step 2. $\mathbb Z_{(2)}[X]$ is Noetherian by Hilbert's Basis Theorem.

Step 3. There is a surjection $\mathbb Z_{(2)}[X] \twoheadrightarrow \Bbb{Z}_{(2)}\left[\sqrt{-3}\right]$, defined by identity on $\mathbb Z_{(2)}$ and $X \mapsto \sqrt{-3}$. The ideals of the codomain of a surjective ring homomorphism are in one-to-one correspondence with a proper subset of the ideals of the domain (specifically, the ideals which contain the kernel of that map - no need to know what that kernel is). The proper subset of ideals automatically satisfies the ascending chain condition.